# Find the distance travelled between $t=0$ and $t=5$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, differentiation, integration, calculus

> The position vector of a particle is given as $\vec r = \frac43 t^{3/2}\hat i - \frac{1}{2} t^2\hat j + 2 \hat k$, $t$ is in seconds. Find the distance travelled between $t = 0$ and $t = 5$ seconds.

I tried it solving by putting values of $t$ as $0$ and $5$ seconds in the position vector, but I couldn't get the answer. (In reality, when I put $t=5$, the equation got really messy.)
Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

> The given answer is $22.5$ m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show some work.

I think your position equation should be
$$\vec r(t)
=\left(\frac{4}{3}t^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\hat\imath
+\left(-\frac{t^{2}}{2}\right)\hat\jmath
+\left(2\ \underline{t}\ \right)\hat k$$
in order to get the value listed in your spoiler.

It's generally a good idea to start with the definitions.

- What is distance? (Don't confuse with "displacement" or with "magnitude of displacement".)
- How do you compute distance traveled when is the motion isn't steady motion?
- What parts do you need to compute the distance?
- How can you compute the needed parts from what you are given?

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for the Effort! : )